# Parent - CHild management in C#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, namespaces

I have a question regarding C# inheritance management.

Should I write both classes (base and derived) under one namespace or should they be in different namespaces?

Answer (score 3):

`Namespace` is nothing else then a part of a complete name of your type.

So to choose either put them into the same `namepsace` or not, is not something that anyone could possibly know here. Choose them according the your *code architecture*.

Immagine being *other* developer and look on your types. Is it intuitive that both of them into the same namespace, or not ?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. But how can I manage them in one namespace? I have one interface, one abstract class and then the child class. Can I put them in different .cs files?

Comment: Sure, you **can** do whatever you want in C#. You can even put them all into the *same* CS file. Destribute them based on your *logic*. **I** personally would put them into the separate files and *may be* even in separate namespaces.

Comment: but if your application is not big one, do not create too articulated model and introduce absolutely unnecessary complexity by using a lot of different namespaces.

Comment: Thanks and I'm sorry for these questions. They might seem very easy but I'm new in C#. I tried putting them in different classes under the same namespace but they didn't work. Is there any missing directive I should write?

Comment: @AliEssa: not clear what you mean saying didn't work. If you can not figure out where problem is add a **new** question with detailed descritpion of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

They don't need to be in the same namespace. You might even put them in different assemblies if the project architecture is like that.